# This code returns an error that says 'Unexpected Null Value'

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
  class FakturPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FakturPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static String id = 'fakturpage';

  @override
  State<FakturPage> createState() => _FakturPageState();
}

class _FakturPageState extends State<FakturPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownTextfield(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the DropdownTextfield widget code, where I tried to make a UI that shows a Textfield and a DropdownButton that has options inputted from the Textfield above it.

```
class DropdownTextfield extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DropdownTextfieldState createState() => _DropdownTextfieldState();
}

class _DropdownTextfieldState extends State<DropdownTextfield> {

  var selectedOption;
  TextEditingController textfieldValue = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> options = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOption = (options.isNotEmpty ? options[0] : null)!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              value = textfieldValue.text;
            });
          },
        ),
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedOption,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedOption = value!;
            });
          },
          items: options.map((option) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: option,
              child: Text(option),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              options.add(textfieldValue.text);
            });
          },
          child: Text("Add Option"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what went wrong. I tried to figure out if my custom dropdown widget is the problem but I can't find anything wrong. I've been trying to fix this for almost an hour without finding the solution, since I'm new to the mobile development world. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are using null-assert(`!`) though you are doing null check.

Replace

```dart
selectedOption = (options.isNotEmpty ? options[0] : null)!;
```

With

```dart
selectedOption = options.isNotEmpty ? options[0] : null;
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about  [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how you are using null-safety Dart feature.

I've tested your code and your DropdownTextfield. Problem is in `options` list which is empty. And the key of this problem is how you use exclamation mark here in DropdownTextfield:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOption = (options.isNotEmpty ? options[0] : null)!;
  }
```

This code works like:

- if `options` list is not empty - take its first value and assign to `selectedOption`
- if its empty - `selectedOption` is null

But adding exclamation mark at the end you are saying Dart compiler that there will not be any null value, so, that's the place where your error is produced.

**How to resolve this?**

- You should define any default value for `selectedOption`
- OR add some elements to the `options` list by default

Also, check out the official Dart [documentation explaining null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) feature: